# Problem running python script with Qlik Sense Desktop

Tags: python, pandas, qliksense

I am trying to run python script inside my load script in Qlik Sense Desktop app.

I know that I need to put `OverrideScriptSecurity=1` in `Settings.ini` and I did it

I leave a shot of how my code looks like

[image: Screenshot 1]

After running the app there is no error

[image: Screenshot 2]

The problem is that the code is not working, because it doesn't do anything. This is my .py code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

import pandas as pd
 
df = pd.read_excel('GRUPOMAS.xlsx')
df.to_csv('HAFUNCIONADO2.csv')
```

I don't know what is wrong, can you help?

I've tried to run the .py with the terminal and it is running ok.